# PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: no such host known

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

I am new in PHP and when I am trying to connect my database with PHP it is showing error

> Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sql_php\pdo.php:2 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sql_php\pdo.php(2):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=port...', 'Rohitash', 'rohitcodes') #1
>   {main} Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\sql_php\pdo.php:2 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sql_php\pdo.php(2):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=port...', 'Rohitash', 'rohitcodes') #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sql_php\pdo.php on line 2

what can be the possible causes for that.

Comment: what are you using for the `hostname`?

Answer (score 2):

The error means your PHP cannot find the host where MySQL server is supposed to be. Please check *if hostname is correct*.

Reading the error message attentively always helps. As you can see from
the stack trace, namely the `__construct('mysql:host=port...',` part, the hostname used begins from the word "port", which doesn't seem to be a valid hostname. Try to use `127.0.0.1` if MySQL is located on the same computer or a correct hostname if it's on some other host.

Note that you **should never do anything like** `try {...} catch(...) {echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();}` as suggested in the other answer. As it will display only the `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed` message but won't provide a clue with incorrect hostname or other important details. Always leave the PDOException alone.

A minimalistic correct example for connecting MySQL would be like this.

First, create a file `database_config.php` that only contains the database credentials,  as they are going to be different on each host

```
<?php
$db_host = '127.0.0.1';
$db_name = 'your database name'
$db_user = 'your username';
$db_pass = 'your password';
$db_port = '3306'; // or the actual port if it's different
```

then create the `database_connection.php` file like this

```
<?php
require __DIR__."/database_config.php";
$dsn = "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;port=$db_port;charset=utf8mb4";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass, $options);
```

and then include this file in any script that needs a database connection.

Note that on a live server you must configure the PHP's `display_errors` option to `off`, so database errors won't be displayed to the end users. Instead, configure the `log_errors` option to `on` so the errors will be logged instead.